# How do I generate thumbnail of map using given Lat/Long in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, thumbnails

I am working on a chat application where I am going to send a map to another user. 
Below is my code to generate a thumbnail of a map. Is there any way to generate a map thumbnail in Objective-C?

Code to generate thumbnail of static map:

```
NSString *staticMapUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color:blue|%@,%@&%@&sensor=true",_lat, _longi,@"zoom=13&size=%dx%d"];
NSURL *mapUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[staticMapUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
UIImage *Mapimage = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:mapUrl]];
```

Save thumbnail images in document directories:

```
NSString *datapathMap=[Locations stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sm_%@_lc_%@.jpg",userid,dateString1]];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:mapUrl];
datapathMap = [datapathMap stringByStandardizingPath];
[urlData writeToFile:datapathMap atomically:YES];
```

Send thumbnail data to bubble to display thumbnail:

```
NSBubbleData *MapSendBubble = [NSBubbleData dataWithImage:mapImage date:[NSDate date] type:BubbleTypeMine];
MapSendBubble.avatar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar1.png"];
[bubbleData addObject:MapSendBubble];
[_bubbleTable reloadData];
```

Send map:

```
NSDate *today=[NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat1 setDateFormat:@"YYYYMMddhhmmss"];
NSString *dateString1=[dateFormat1 stringFromDate:today];

NSString *userid= @"mc1";     NSString *latlong=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[_lat substringToIndex:2],[_longi substringToIndex:2]];
[map setTag:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",latlong] integerValue]];

NSString *longlat=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",_longi,_lat];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *date=[dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

//Find a cache directory. You could consider using documents dir instead  (depends on the data you are fetching)
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [paths  objectAtIndex:0];

NSError *error;
NSString *MainFolder = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/SmoothChat"]];
NSString *Locations=[MainFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Locations"]];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:MainFolder])
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:MainFolder withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
}
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:Locations])
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:Locations withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
}

NSString *staticMapUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color:red|%@,%@&%@&sensor=true",_lat,_longi,@"zoom=15&size=300x180"];
NSURL *mapUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[staticMapUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

UIImage *Mapimage = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:mapUrl]];

NSString *datapathMap=[Locations stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sm_%@_lc_%@.jpg",userid,dateString1]];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:mapUrl];
datapathMap = [datapathMap stringByStandardizingPath];
[urlData writeToFile:datapathMap atomically:YES];


//  NSString *uuid1 = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
//    [self sendXMPPMessage:1 :[NSString stringWithFormat:@"lc%@",value] :[NSString stringWithFormat:@"oi_%@_lc_%@.jpg",userid,dateString1] :@"" :jsonstring :[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",longlat] :_user :@"" :@"" :@"" :[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"current_chat"] :@"" :@"" :_senderType :[self currentDateTme] :0];

NSBubbleData *photoBubble11 = [NSBubbleData dataWithImage:staticMapUrl date:[NSDate date] type:BubbleTypeMine];
photoBubble11.avatar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar1.png"];

[bubbleData addObject:photoBubble11];
[_bubbleTable reloadData];
[self goToBottom];

[map setHidden:YES];
[blurView setHidden:YES];
[_NewView setHidden:YES];

[map removeAnnotation:point];
currentLocation=nil;
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: Hi Avinash, welcome to [so]. What problem are you facing, exactly? If you already have the code to generate map thumbnail, why are you asking for code to generate map thumbnail? Are you seeing an error message? Or are you having a missing piece of code? Can you clarify? Thanks.

Comment: mapUrl is not converted into UIImage.

Comment: please provide your mail will send you complete details.

Comment: ERROR MESSAGE //     *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000011a550'

Comment: Hi Avinash, I suggest you to read **[this help center page - How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.